# formatting paragraph with array on css sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So I have a HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files; 
I have an array in my JavaScript file and I made an empty paragraph in my html file, then changed the `innerHTML` of the paragraph with id "par" to display the array. When I run the html, the array is displayed but it continues off on the page that I need to scroll right to view it all. I want it to fill up the whole page, and break up into lines, but I cannot seem to figure out how.

In my CSS file, I have tried doing

```
#par {width: 150px;height: 150px;}
```

and even tried messing around with font-align but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: `150` needs `px` after it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<pre>` tag for handling your literal input. Also see the [`white-space` property of CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). This will literally interpret your input like a `<pre>` tag would.

Try `white-space: pre` and see if that suits your needs. If you are not formatting your array and want it to automatically break once it hits the edge of the screen, try `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "par" as id of html element on your page, you need to update your css and change the dot to hash as:

```
#par {width: 150px;height: 150px;}
```

Comment: oops that was a technical mistake while posting this question. I used # in my .css. But my format is still off